# Regex - find specific pattern not surrounded by []

Tags: javascript, regex

In given random string: `'#id1 .class1 .1class [price="23 .23 "] .7ytr"`

I want to replace the pattern - dots followed by number followed by {n} alpha numeric like: `.8acb8`

But ignore it when it's surrounded by "[]" like - `[price="23 .23 "]`.

For now I wrote only the pattern I need to find without ignoring []:

```
str.replace(/\.(\d+\w+)/g, '[class="$1"]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to use negative lookaheads:

```
\.\d\w+(?![^[]*\])
```

***Explanations***:

```
\.\d\w+         # Any dot followed by a number followed by alpha-numeric characters
(?![^[]*\])     # Which is not inside brackets (Negative Lookahead)
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wZ6eY4/2)**

Comment: or `\.\d\w+(?=[^\[\]]*(?:\[|$))`

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[^]]*\]|(\.\d\w+)
```

Try this.Grab the captures or matches.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qU4wM7/1

Comment: I wanted to avoid the other ones inside [], and you regex not skip them

Comment: @user959210 if you use `match` then it will skip `[]`.That was thething used here.